# Running asynchronous functions throws an error

Tags: python

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5JK8.png) I am trying to write a script that runs a .exe file using a silent installer with python. My main problem is that when the installer finishes it request a user input - see screenshot attached and the script will not finish until the user hit any key to start the services

Therefore, I wrote a script that has two functions running asynchronous
As expected I am having errors

My expectations: Function `click_window` will wait for function run_installer to finish and then it will click enter in the cmd.exe window - I will add a screenshot

What is happening:  The Script runs as expected but when it gets to `os.system = (file + '/SILENT')` base on the debugger - it dies out with an error message

```js
import asyncio
import subprocess
import time

import pyautogui
import pywinauto

from pyautogui import getWindowsWithTitle
import pygetwindow


async def click_window():
    # Wait for everything to load in, windows, apps etc.
    # You may need to adjust this timing for your system.
    time.sleep(10)

    # We are waiting for the window to open up and then click ok
    app = pywinauto.Application()

    # Tell Pyautogui what the windows name is.
    Win = "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe"

    # wait for the window to appear
    app = pywinauto.Application()
    app.WindowSpecification.wait(Win)
    app.window_(title=Win).SetFocus()
    app.window_(title=Win).TypeKeys("Enter")

 

    # keyboard shortcut R to hit 'Run Cleaner' button,
    pyautogui.press('Enter')

    # Wait 15 seconds to give time for the cleaning operation.
    # You may need to adjust.
    time.sleep(15)

    # Move mouse to exit button and click.
    # pyautogui.moveTo(1905, 10, 1)
    pyautogui.click()
    print("We did it")


async def run_installer():
    import fnmatch
    import glob
    import os
    import shutil
    import time
    import urllib.request
    import zipfile

    # Download the installer
    url = 'http://build.****.com:8080/job/CI_build_***_grs_master_windows_mysql/lastBuild/artifact/com.****.sdm.****/target/release/*zip*/release.zip'

    file_name = 'release.zip'

    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)

    time.sleep(120)

    print("Download is done")

    file_name = "release.zip"

    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zip:
        # printing all the contents of the zip file

        zip.printdir()
        time.sleep(60)
        # extracting all the files
        print('Extracting all the files now...')
        zip.extractall()

    print('I am done extracting Done!')

    print("Path at terminal when executing this file")
    print(os.getcwd() + "\n")

    os.chdir("C:\\Users\\****\\PycharmProjects\\Phyton-Project\\release")

    print("Path at terminal when executing this file again")
    print(os.getcwd() + "\n")

    # Checking installer directory
    for file in glob.glob("*.exe"):
        print(file + "   Here is the file found")
        # file variable contains installer
    time.sleep(120)

    # Adding permissions to installer to run/execute
    os.chmod("C:\\Users\\****\\PycharmProjects\\Phyton-Project\\release", 0o777)  # read/write by everyone

    for file in os.listdir('.'):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.exe'):
            print("here is the file" + file)
            # file variable is the exe installer

    time.sleep(120)
    print("Installation starts")

    os.system = (file + '/SILENT')


# time.sleep(360)

start = time.time()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

tasks = [
    asyncio.gather(run_installer()),
    asyncio.gather(click_window()),
]

loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
loop.close()

end = time.time()
print("Total time: {}".format(end - start))
```

Expected Results:
Function run installer finish and the window opens up to start up the services and then the click_window function starts up and clicks on the window and after 4 clicks for every service the script finish

Actual Results:
Function run installer runs but it dies at   `os.system = (file + '/SILENT')` because the installer never installs and then it throws the following error message:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 192.5728.105)
I am done waiting
File Name                                             Modified             Size
release/pa****_**_5.4.3_20190903_win_x64_db.exe 2019-09-03 22:29:42    757267728
Extracting all the files now...
Done!
Path at terminal when executing this file
C:\Users\j****\PycharmProjects\Phyton-Project

Path at terminal when executing this file again
C:\Users\j*****\PycharmProjects\Phyton-Project\release

pa***_***_5.4.3_20190903_win_x64_db.exe   Here is the file found
here is the fileparasoft_dtp_5.4.3_20190903_win_x64_db.exe
Installation starts
Total time: 485.42616963386536
_GatheringFuture exception was never retrieved
future: <_GatheringFuture finished exception=AppNotConnected('Please use start or connect before trying anything else')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/****/PycharmProjects/Phyton-Project/DTP-Installation.py", line 27, in click_window
    app.WindowSpecification.wait(Win)
  File "C:\Users\****\PycharmProjects\Phyton-Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1234, in __getattribute__
    return self[attr_name]
  File "C:\Users\****\PycharmProjects\Phyton-Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1220, in __getitem__
    return self.window(best_match=key)
  File "C:\Users\*****\PycharmProjects\Phyton-Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1207, in window
    raise AppNotConnected("Please use start or connect before trying "
pywinauto.application.AppNotConnected: Please use start or connect before trying anything else

Process finished with exit code
```

Comment: After  the loop   `for file in os.listdir('.'):`, **file** has the value which is the last file in os.listdir() and need not be the .exe file as you are not breaking the loop when you find the match. Are you sure, is this supposed to work like this?

Comment: yes it works as expected when only using the function def run_installer without using asynchronous. Installer finish but it gets stuck at the screenshot - I don't know how can I click in that screen therefore - I used the asynchronous

Comment: The error pasted here is not related to installation method but to the clickwindow method in which you need to connect the application already running using `app.connect()` please refer: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowTo.html?highlight=connect(#how-to-specify-a-usable-application-instance

Comment: @SajeerNoohukannu Thank you let me try that - One more question about your comments: The error pasted here is not related to installation method but to the click window method - if that's the case why the installation doesn't start at all? I am not questioning your answer - I just want to understand because, to be honest, I am lost because in my mind one function will run and finish and the other function will start up.

Comment: I make my click_window definition just to this: async def click_window():
    # Wait for everything to load in, windows, apps etc.
    # You may need to adjust this timing for your system.
    # time.sleep(10)

    app = Application().connect(path=r"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe")

    print("We did it")  and now it's failing with this

Comment: _GatheringFuture exception was never retrieved
future: <_GatheringFuture finished exception=ProcessNotFoundError('Process "c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe" not found!')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jromero\PycharmProjects\Phyton-Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)

Answer (score 0):

ok I decided to create a new function to click on the window - so far I can find the window, set the focus but I can't click enter or any key

```js
import win32con
import win32gui
import pyautogui as pg
from pywinauto.win32structures import HANDLE

toplist = []
winlist = []


def enum_callback(hwnd, results): winlist.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))


win32gui.EnumWindows(enum_callback, toplist)
services = [(hwnd, title) for hwnd, title in winlist if 'system32' in title.lower()]
# just grab the first window that matches
services = services[0]
# use the window handle to set focus
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(services[0])

win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()

# print windows title
print("Windows Title")
print(services)

print('FOUND')

win32gui.EnableWindow(1, True)

win32api.SendMessage(services, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_F11, 0)


print('Window Close')



Response:

C:\Users\jromero\PycharmProjects\Phyton-Project\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/jromero/PycharmProjects/Phyton-Project/click-enter.py
Windows Title
Traceback (most recent call last):
(334514, 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe')
  File "C:/Users/jromero/PycharmProjects/Phyton-Project/click-enter.py", line 32, in <module>
FOUND
    win32api.SendMessage(services, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_F11, 0)
TypeError: The object is not a PyHANDLE object

Process finished with exit code 1
```